# Can a MacBook Pro A1708 power on with the battery disconnected?

Tags: macbook-pro

I have here a MacBook Pro A1708 (MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2017, 2 Thunderbolt ports) that's refusing to power on - as in, come to life at all.

It's one of those models that's very hard to tell if anything is happening, because there's no MagSafe light or start-up bong for feedback. I don't know if the fan would normally give a little twitch at power-on.

Could a faulty battery prevent power-on? And can it (try to) power on with the battery power connector and battery data cable both disconnected?

Comment: This really needs a "hands-on, eyes-on" examination, as different hardware problems can manifest different results. Take it to an Apple Store, or other Apple-certified repair shop. An Apple Store will give you a diagnosis for free. (Your Mac was sold until July 2019, so is still within the 5-year hardware support window.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is: yes, it can power on (though will run in a low-performance mode, I am not sure why).

Failure to power on is likely (once such things as SMC reset have been taken care of) a fatal logic board issue.

Comment: It runs in low-performance mode, because the CPU at high usage levels requires a lot more power than the power cable can supply. The power cable is designed to charge the battery; the battery is designed to power the laptop.